# AJAX loading gif different for different form submits

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I have 3 forms. I want to show 3 different gifs when i submit different submits, but instead, it shows the same image for all the three. Also, its inconsistent as sometimes it shows the gif on first click and then not on the next two clicks, sometimes it shows on all three, but after that if I click on submit again result is shown but it does not show to loading gif image. Here is my code:

```
<div id="wait"
  style="display: none; width: 32px; height: 43px; 
      position: absolute; top: 75%; left: 75%; padding: 2px;">
  <!-- this is one of the gifs -->
  <img src="images/demo_wait.gif" width="32" height="32" />
    <br> <br>Please Wait
</div>

    <div class="container">

        <h4 style="color: #447099;">Select a region to proceed</h4>
        <br> To Schedule:
        <form id="myform1" name="myform1"
            action="/AWSCustomerJavaWebFinal/ServiceAmazon" method="get"
            onsubmit="return promptMessage()">
            <select name="availableRegion" id="availableRegion"
                style="width: 142px; margin-left: 15px;" class="btn btn-primary">
                <option value="sr">Select Region</option>
                <option value="us-east-1">North Virginia</option>

            </select> Instance ID<input type="text" name="instanceId"> <input
                type="submit" id=button1 value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

            <div id='content2'></div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var form2 = $('#myform1');
            form2.submit(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type : form2.attr('method'),
                    url : form2.attr('action'),
                    data : form2.serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        var result2 = data;
                        $('#content2').html(result2);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
                });
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
                });
            });
        </script>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>View Instance Status:</h3>

        <form id="myform2" name="myform2"
            action="/AWSCustomerJavaWebFinal/ServiceInstances" method="get"
            onsubmit="return messagePrompt()">
            <select name="availableRegion" id="availableRegion"
                style="width: 142px; margin-left: 15px;" class="btn btn-primary">
                <option value="sr">Select Region</option>
                <option value="us-east-1">North Virginia</option>

            </select> <input type="submit" value="View Status" id="button2"
                class="btn btn-primary"><br></br>
            <div id='content'></div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = $('#myform2');
            form.submit(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type : form.attr('method'),
                    url : form.attr('action'),
                    data : form.serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        var result = data;
                        $('#content').html(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
                });
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <br>
</fieldset>
<div class="container">
    <form id="myform3" name="myform3" action="viewSchedule.jsp"
        method="get">
        <br> To view Schedule: <input type="submit"
            value="View Schedule" id="button3" class="btn btn-primary">

        <div id='content1'></div>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form1 = $('#myform3');
        form1.submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : form1.attr('method'),
                url : form1.attr('action'),
                data : form1.serialize(),
                success : function(data) {
                    var result1 = data;
                    $('#content1').html(result1);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                $("#wait").css("display", "block");
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I tried to use different div ids for 3 different images wait, wait1 and wait3, changed waits in this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                $("#wait").css("display", "block");
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
```

and added the div id=wait inside the 3 different div containers, nothing seems to work.

Comment: I can see only 1 gif: <img src="images/demo_wait.gif" width="32" height="32" />. where are the other two?

Comment: @Jan I removed them because when i add them i get 3 gifs on click of one submit!

Comment: then you should consider setting new src to them on submit - that way image (tag) stays the same while image (display) changes

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way (form2 as example for all of them, see comments on changes)

```
<div id="wait"
  style="display: none; width: 32px; height: 43px; 
      position: absolute; top: 75%; left: 75%; padding: 2px;">
  <!-- Add ID to image to make it addressable -->
  <img id="waitimage" src="images/demo_wait.gif"
                width="32" height="32" />
    <br> <br>Please Wait
</div>


      form2.submit(function() {
            //Set correct wait image
            $("$waitimage").src = "images/demo_wait2.gif";
            //Show WAIT
            $("#wait").css("display", "block");
            //Perform call
            $.ajax({
                type : form2.attr('method'),
                url : form2.attr('action'),
                data : form2.serialize(),
                success : function(data) {
                    var result2 = data;
                    $('#content2').html(result2);
                    //HIDE wait
                    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: It submits the form automatically after doing this and redirects to another page.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do to it is:

1. I would create a template of gif.
2. Then i would prepend it in the specific form when submit happens.
3. when ajax gets completed i would remove it from the form.

---

Like this:

#### 1. template creation:

```
var loadingGif = '<div class="wait">'+
                 '<img src="images/demo_wait.gif" width="32" height="32" />'+
                 '<br> <br>Please Wait'+
                 '</div>';
```

#### 2. when form submit happens i would append it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loaderObj = {
       showGif : function(form){
            var loadingGif = '<div class="wait">'+
                 '<img src="images/demo_wait.gif" width="32" height="32" />'+
                 '<br> <br>Please Wait'+
                 '</div>';
            form.prepend(loadingGif); // <----prepend it here.
       },
       removeGif : function(form){
          form.find('.wait').remove();  // <--------remove it here.
       }
    };
    var form2 = $('#myform1');
    form2.submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : form2.attr('method'),
            url : form2.attr('action'),
            data : form2.serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
                loaderObj.showGif(form);  //<-----show the loading gif here.
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var result2 = data;
                $('#content2').html(result2);
            },
            complete:function(){
               loaderObj.removeGif(form);  //<-----call to remove here.
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, doesn't show the gif and redirects to another page.

Comment: Define doesn't work? You should add the code to all forms.

Comment: I tried doing it for one form first, it didn't show the result on the same page, redirected to another page and displayed result there.